# Do WPF and Silverlight use the same classes for basic drawing?

Tags: c#, wpf, silverlight

Do WPF and Silverlight use the same interfaces and basic shapes defined inside system. Or is WPF defined different inside system than Silverlight ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This somewhat depends on what you mean by *"the same"*, if you mean the implementation of classes with the same name which serve the same purpose in both frameworks you can use a decompiler of your choice (e.g. [ILSpy](http://wiki.sharpdevelop.net/ilspy.ashx)) to open the relevant assemblies and compare the code.